# AWS Lambda Python PIL/pillow import error

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to deploy a simple service to AWS Lambda (on Python 3.6) that requires PIL.  I'm using the serverless framework, so to start I simply did `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` on an ec2 instance with my code and all of the dependencies installed, and when I called the Lambda function I got the following error (from CloudWatch logs):

`Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'PIL'`

I then tried to install & package pillow manually by doing `pip3 install pillow -t .vendor` and added the following to my serverless.yml:

`package:
  include:
    - .vendor/**`

But I'm still getting the same error.  Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: It seems that not using the serverless architecture and instead packaging the dependencies myself fixed the issue.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because **pillow** is not a standard python library found in AWS Lambda environment by default. To include and use it in your code you need to make a custom deployment package with all your dependicies and your code included and then deploy it.

And this is what you did to make it run.